# upgraded iOS 14 at iPhone 11 , facing UIPickerview issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, xcode

I have been using UIPickerView and used Objective-c in my project , but recently upgraded ios14.2 in iPhoone11 .
Please check the image ,...Actually it should show the data in three components

[Used UIPickerView to display the data from DB[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Oji.png)

Please help me to find and resolve the issue
-Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: show your tried code, as well as please go through the release notes of latest

Comment: Thank you for your time and reply Mr. Anbu.Karthik
Yes  Anbu.Karthik, gone through the release notes, but could not find modifications for UIPickerview

Answer (score 0):

If you used "`UIDatePicker`", try this:

```
...

if (@available(iOS 13.4, *)) {
                _datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyleWheels;
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }

...
```

Comment: #Dear Sargis
Tthank you verymuch for your reply and time , Actually i used UIPickerview , Which is working perfect at ios13 but not ios14

Comment: Ah, ok. It's strange, because for UIPickerview, not any changes in iOS 14